# How to quickly remove all useless iOS applications on my Mac?

Tags: mac, applications

I have 900 apps on my Mac because I sync both my iPhone and iPad.

There are a lot of apps that I deleted a long time ago which are useless. I have amassed 40gb of apps.

Is there a quick way to delete all the useless apps?

Answer (score 2):

You could right click on any app in iTunes `Apps` section, click `Show in Finder`, then sort by `Date Modified` and erase all those that haven't been updated in a long time and that you don't use. Be careful because one of your preferred app might not have been updated recently.